# How to stop a service before executing an ExecStart entry?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I would like to set up a Timer which will stop a service, execute a script and restart the service.

One of the possibilities is to use

```
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/systemctl stop myservice
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl start myservice
```

Another one is to have `myscript.sh` handling the whole thing, including `systemctl`.

I find it awkward, though, to use `systemctl` within a service declaration, when there may be systemd built-in mechanisms to interact with services. Is there a cleaner way to perform these operations?

Comment: Can you give more context here? Why do you need `myservice` to be stopped during the run of `myscript.sh`? There's nothing essentially wrong with using `systemctl` inside a service (and you probably won't find a solution that doesn't involve using it), but perhaps, depending on what `myscript.sh` is doing, you could just hook it into `myservice.service` directly (in an `ExecStartPre=`, perhaps checking if it needs to run) and then just having the timer launch a `systemctl restart myservice` instead... Just an idea. Having more context on what you're trying to do would help here.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger: this is a Timer which will perform a backup. The service backed up needs first to be stopped, then restarted afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By (ab?)using the WatchdogSec the service will terminate when it fails to acknowledge within the time. It will then restart, but execute the script first.

```
WatchdogSec={interval}
Restart=on-watchdog
ExecStopPost=/script.sh
```

ref: [WatchdogSec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#WatchdogSec=)

Having the service being able to be backed up while running would be a much nicer service.